# Make a custom yosemite install image on os x

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, osx-server, dmg-image

I'm in charge of reinstalling os x on the computers of every new hire in our company. We're just starting to learn about the awesome things that you can do with OS X Server including NetInstall. I know that it's possible to create a custom OS X image, but I can't figure out how.

What I would like to be able to do is create a NetInstall image that:

- creates an administrator account
- creates the users account
- applies various default settings
- comes prepackaged with certain software
- and installs without the need for user interference

I know that this is all possible, I just can't find any kind of tutorial that explains how to do it in Yosemite or even Mavericks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an extra partition on your with Disk Utility. Download Yosemite from Appstore. Install it on the partition. Reboot from it and do your things. Reboot from the normal partition.

1. Launch Server.app
2. Select 'System Image Utility' from the Tools menu of Server.app
3. Verify that your partition appears in the header.
4. Select the 'NetRestore Image' radio button, click 'Continue'
5. Store the image in the directory /Library/NetBoot/NetBootSP0
6. Enable NetInstall under the advanced options of Server.app.

Comment: Do you think you could go into a little more detail on how to make a NetRestore image?

Comment: edited the answer with details.